# Make the value return timespan(0), if rows not available or condition is not met in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have the following code:

```
Telemetry
| where DataMetadata["category"] == "Warning"
| summarize 
        Duration = sum(case(Name == "Event", totimespan(Value), totimespan(0))),
        Text = min(case(Name == "Information", tostring(Value), "N/A")),
        DeviceID = min(case(Name == "Ident", tostring(Value), "N/A"))
        by Timestamp
| summarize TotalDuration = sum(Duration) by Text,DeviceID
| top 2 by TotalDuration
| summarize Duration = max(case(isnotnull(TotalDuration) or isnotempty(TotalDuration), strcat("Duration: ",format_timespan(TotalDuration, 'dd:hh:mm:ss'), "[sec] ",DeviceID," - ",Text), tostring(timespan(0))))
```

Checking the last hour of data, the condition DataMetadata["category"] == "Warning" **is not met** and in this case I want to display as a result 00:00:00:00 as shown in the summarize at the end of the code.

However, what I get as a result is the following:

[image]

What is the issue here and how can I solve it ?

Comment: Why do you assume that there's an issue?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz The issue is that based on what I have as a default result in the case statement why am I not seeing anything, shouldn't I be getting timespan(0) or am I missing something here ? Is it possible to show something as output if the first condition was not met ?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz So there is no possibility to add any default result in this case or is there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you do want the top 2 records by `TotalDuration`, in case there are any.

```
let Telemetry = datatable(DataMetadata:dynamic, Name:string, Timestamp:datetime, Value:string)[];
Telemetry
| where DataMetadata["category"] == "Warning"
| summarize 
        Duration = sum(case(Name == "Event", totimespan(Value), totimespan(0))),
        Text = min(case(Name == "Information", tostring(Value), "N/A")),
        DeviceID = min(case(Name == "Ident", tostring(Value), "N/A"))
        by Timestamp
| summarize TotalDuration = sum(Duration) by Text,DeviceID
| union (print TotalDuration = 0s, Text = "NA", DeviceID = "NA")
| top 2 by TotalDuration
| project Duration = strcat("Duration: ",format_timespan(TotalDuration, 'dd:hh:mm:ss'), "[sec] ",DeviceID," - ",Text)
```

| Duration |
| --- |
| Duration: 00:00:00:00[sec] NA - NA |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22RMW/CMBCFdyT+w8kLseSqqGMqBqR0YChT1A4IVSa5klSxE9kX2lT98T2HBgglHiKf731+91whQYoVGiTXwQJyTbx2FUYJ/5+RdKjEeWe1KTMFa20w9uRKu1eQlgY9adPE3ITEOwUvumqHDrnZPk4nJ/x08gOfBTqES/ZGZCze164TW1gsQLxqZ1ksQrtvjdGu/EaYTuDvS1qnqawtu+XjKNMeo2CrFz8d0JJQQHWw4xtto96RHJXmUkp1Jqb4RUwzpb2irex77Ux/W888jnUiivX9UoxICR7KDFfJbVo+eLvNOWN23TnbcQxpTbq6SmDYyl7Hs6jBRtC2NnRGDd9I/+Rzr4bpxXrJ3i4GCAUZCFQ38NCzL9XhpHH1B2Y0ehJy/J6RGEoxCHUM8e0U/4ijYJbncVHExsTez0IcG4/ZlnWDGSXgjrfBqPwFOZE9SbECAAA=)